# How to add Admob in Ionic apps?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying add Admob in my app maded with Ionic. The problem is that banner not is displaied.

To add Admob I'm following this [sample](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ionic/adding-admob-to-ionic-framework-application-step-by-step/) but does not works, the admob not is shown.

How to add Admob in Ionic apps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used admob using [this](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro) plugin in my project.It is worked perfectly

1.Create a `admob_simple.js` file and place in www/js folder

**admob_simple.js**

```
var admobid = {};
if (/(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    admobid = { // for Android
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-1417132269349730/9915914608',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-1417132269349730/8159979806'
    };
} else if (/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    admobid = { // for iOS
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/4806197152',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/7563979554'
    };
} else {
    admobid = { // for Windows Phone
        banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/8878394753',
        interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/1355127956'
    };
}

if ((/(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent))) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
} else {
    initApp();
}

function initApp() {
    if (!window.AdMob) {
        return;
    }
    window.AdMob.createBanner({
        adId: 'ca-app-pub-1417132269349730/9915914608',
        position: window.AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
        autoShow: true

    });

}
```

NB:Please change `banner` & `interstitial` ids

2.Add below line in your `index.html`

```
<script src="js/admob_simple.js"></script>
```

If you have any doubt.Please let me know.Thanks

Comment: after add the banner of Admob, when I do press back button of device(android), the app is closed, not back to other views, is it normal ? before add Admob back normally.

Comment: @FernandoPaiva:Glad to help you

Comment: @FernandoPaiva:It is not normal.Some problem in your routing